# How to print multiple results to a single text file in C?

Tags: c, file-io, io, user-input, io-redirection

So I have an assignment where I am to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle. My professor want me to use 2 sets of sample data and print the results to a single txt file using I/O. I can get 1 set of data to print the txt file but not both. How do I do this using this terminal command ?:

> ./Lab0 > input.txt>output3.txt

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

float length, width, area, perimeter;

printf("\nEnter the Length of Rectangle : ");
scanf("%f", &length);

printf("\nEnter the Width of Rectangle : ");
scanf("%f", &width);

area = length * width;
perimeter = 2 * (length + width);
printf("\nArea of Rectangle : %f", area);
printf("\nPerimeter of rectangle : %f ", perimeter);
return (0);
}
```

Here is his instructions:

> Prompt the user for the two sides of a rectangle (length and width).  Compute the area of the rectangle as the product of the length and width using variables of type “float” in “C”.  Print the area of the rectangle and its perimeter.  The perimeter of a rectangle is the sum of twice the length plus twice the width.  You may assume the user enters both the length and width using the same units.  For full credit, your program must exhibit appropriate prompts for user input and appropriate labels for the output (area and perimeter).
>
> Test your program using a length of 5.32733 inches and width 6.8875899 inches.  Also test your program with a length of 10.0 meters and width of 5.347863 meters.

I/O instructions

> "RESTRICTION: Management will not accept “screen shots.”  Ideally your program should read all data from a text file and print the results to a text file.  Microsoft expects all lines to terminate with a   sequence.  UNIX does not terminate lines in a text file using this convention.  You can take a file produced in UNIX and read/print it properly on a Microsoft system using software such as “TextPad” on university workstations.  TextPad is an example of software designed to determine the origin of a file and interpret the results according to th operating system utilized. You may use I/O redirection at the command prompt of physically open and close files.  As an example assume an executable Pgm1 that normally reads from the keyboard and writers to the screen.  “Pgm1 < Pgm1.dat” would obtain input from the text file “Pgm1.dat” and write to the screen. “Pgm1 > Pgm1.out” would read from the keyboard and print the result in the text file “Pgm1.out.”  “Pgm1  Pgm1.out” would read from the text file Pgm1.dat and print results in the text file “Pgm1.out.”"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what's in `input.txt`? Do its contents need to be fed into your program?

Comment: I think ideally it's supposed to because he mentioned it in the instructions but I do not know how to feed that info into my program

Comment: `./Lab0 < input.txt > output3.txt`

Comment: Of course, your prompts are going to wind up in your output, so you'll need to change your code to deal with that.  Quite frankly, prompting for this data is bad practice, and I would tell the professor that.  Of course, I'm not in the class.

Comment: nothing in statement of work suggests to me you need to use io redirection or write anything to a file. It simply says prompt the user and print out the result. More to this question than youre showing? Where did you get the idea to read from and write to file?

Comment: Yes @yano , I just updated the question with the I/O instructions. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You would normally run something like this from the command prompt:

```
./Lab0 < input1.txt > output3.txt
./Lab0 < input2.txt >> output3.txt
```

Then you will have a complete output3.txt with the results of both program runs.

Another idea is to have the program itself open the output file for appending.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  float length, width, area, perimeter;

  FILE *fp = stdout;

  if (argc>1) {
    char *append_fn = argv[1];
    fp = fopen(append_fn, "a+");
  }

  printf("\nEnter the Length of Rectangle : ");
  scanf("%f", &length);

  printf("\nEnter the Width of Rectangle : ");
  scanf("%f", &width);

  area = length * width;
  perimeter = 2 * (length + width);
  fprintf(fp, "\nArea of Rectangle : %f", area);
  fprintf(fp, "\nPerimeter of rectangle : %f ", perimeter);

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;

}
```

You would run the above program as follows:

```
./prog out1.txt
./prog out1.txt
```

Inputting the values at the terminal each time. The output file will have both program runs.